# Class Modules in Far-Off Places

Tags: python, git, python-3.x, github, python-module

Class Modules have to be in the working directory in order to be imported to a python program.  However, I want to keep my individual main programs in separate directories based on use, and not have all programs and all classes jammed into one enormous directory.

What can I add to my scripts to point them to the correct module directory? Even better: can I make my module directory on a repo like GitHub and import for from there?

Comment: I don't think Python modules need to be in the working directory. They just have to be in some location listed in your PYTHONPATH environment variable. No, they can't just be directly on the Internet somewhere - that would mean you'd need Internet access to run your program.

Comment: Would I have to set that path as a BASH script each time I start a new terminal session? BTW, I'm not concerned with needing internet access, as my program needs it to run anyway.

Comment: You can set it anywhere environment variables are set - ~/.profile, /etc/profile, about a dozen other places... Or you can install your modules to one of the locations that's already in the default PYTHONPATH, like /usr/local/lib, and not have to alter the variable at all. You can see everywhere that's searched for Python modules by doing a `print sys.path` in your Python interpreter.

Comment: I added my modules to /usr/lib/python3.3 and it seems to work now.  Thanks.  Why don't you post your response as an answer so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python modules need to be somewhere in Python's search path.  This happens to include the working directory.

There are many places to store one's modules, possibly the easiest is

```
/usr/local/lib/pythonx.y/site-packages
```

or

```
/usr/local/lib/pythonx.y/dist-packages
```

(whichever one is on your system).

Once in there you should create a directory for your stuff, create an empty `__init__.py` file in that directory, then copy your modules into it:

```
sudo mkdir MyStuff
sudo touch MyStuff/__init__.py
sudo cp /home/me/my_module1.py MyStuff/
sudo cp /home/me/my_module2.py MyStuff/
```

and then in your scripts you can

```
from MyStuff import my_module1
```